# iOS APNS Push Notifications not received for last devices

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I have an iOS app with rss feeds, it has iOS push notification service , the push notifications works fine for some devices (the previous devices ) , but the new or last devices are not receive the push notifications for this app at all . I think the error is in my php script , but I don't know how I can solve it , the host of my website that connecting with my app is BlueHost.com .

-Error log is :

`[08-Aug-2013 11:00:14 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /home3/basiphon/public_html/Push.php on line 56
[08-Aug-2013 11:15:24 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): SSL: crypto enabling timeout in /home3/basiphon/public_html/Push.php on line 56
[08-Aug-2013 11:15:24 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /home3/basiphon/public_html/Push.php on line 56
[08-Aug-2013 11:15:24 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /home3/basiphon/public_html/Push.php on line 56
[08-Aug-2013 11:30:33 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out) in /home3/basiphon/public_html/Push.php on line 56
[08-Aug-2013 11:46:39 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out) in /home3/basiphon/public_html/Push.php on line 56`

-My PHP script

```
    // Open a connection to the APNS server

    $fp = stream_socket_client(
        $url, $err,
        $errstr, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$result)
        echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
    {
        echo 'Message successfully delivered111' . PHP_EOL;
        $query_update="update wp_apns_messages set status='delivered',delivery=NOW() where pid='$pid'";
        $res_update=mysql_query($query_update) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);
}
```

`//echo "***";
?>
</body>
</html>  </i>`

Comment: seeing your logs it seems that you are sending push notifications in production mode. first confirm that there is no development notification id in your list. if there is development notification id is there it sometime choke the sending of notification. So try sending the notification in opposite order to conform this.

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes I send the push notification in production mode, my app is already live in apple store .. do I need to erase the development certificate from the script and keep the production certificate only ?

Comment: there is no need to remove development certificate but make sure there is no notification id in your database on which you are trying to send push notification from production mode.